# How to implement thread safe local static variable in C++03?

Tags: c++, multithreading, static, initialization, c++03

Before C++11 local static variables were not thread safe. I need to initialize a static variable in a performance critical function with a result of some non-reentrant function.

I would like to see a static variable initialization which uses mutexes or other synchronization primitives, but has some opportunistic check of a regular static variable to reduce the mutex use in a typical situation when the variable has already been initialized a long ago. It seems GCC implements something like this for C++11, as mentioned in [Static initialization and thread safety](http://anotherlayer.net/2012/05/04/static-initialization-and-thread-safety/), but the code listed there is not complete and is assembly only.

Note:  There is plenty of questions asking IF the static variable initialization is atomic on Stack Overflow, but they seem to be content with the answer "no" and they do not seems to show a practical solution (like [C++ Static Initializer - Is it thread safe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2730105/c-static-initializer-is-it-thread-safe)).

Comment: There is no portable solution in C++03 because in C++03 there is no concept of threads. You have to ask your OS for help. And I do not know your OS, so I can not help you.

Comment: @knivil I am looking for a practical solution, not necessarily a portable one (but it would be handy to have the non-portable part isolated). Assuming I have a portable mutex at my disposal (which sounds reasonable, as almost all platforms have some kind of mutex), how could the thread safe solution look like?

Comment: If you do not want boost then pthread_once for POSIX and .... (?) for windows.

Comment: I attempted to write a mutex based implementation myself and quickly realized it is more complicated than it seems. The trouble is the mutex object itself cannot be used before initialized, and its initialization needs to be thread safe, or done before the function is ever called. This is probably why GCC went for a global mutex originally. I will probably check how does recent GCC solve this (or how is boost or std call_once implemented).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I discussed this in a [follow-up](http://anotherlayer.net/2013/09/20/51/) to the blog post referenced in the question. If for some reason you can't use `boost::call_once` your block-scoped static is a pointer, POD, or has a thread-safe constructor, you can write the same initialization guard code that GCC would emit:

```
// Define a static local variable once, safely, for MSVC
//
// This macro is necessary because MSVC pre-2013 doesn't
// properly implement C++11 static local initialization.
// It is equivalent to writing something like
//
//     static type var = stmt;
//
// in a compliant compiler (e.g. GCC since who knows when)

// States for lock checking
enum { uninitialized = 0, initializing, initialized };

// Preprocessor hackery for anonymous variables
#define PASTE_IMPL(x, y) x ## y
#define PASTE(x, y) PASTE_IMPL(x, y)
#define ANON_VAR(var) PASTE(var, __LINE__)

#define STATIC_DEFINE_ONCE(type, var, stmt)                     \
    static type var;                                            \
    static int ANON_VAR(state);                                 \
    bool ANON_VAR(cont) = true;                                 \
    while (ANON_VAR(cont)) {                                    \
        switch (InterlockedCompareExchange(&ANON_VAR(state),    \
                initializing, uninitialized)) {                 \
        case uninitialized:                                     \
            var = stmt;                                         \
            InterlockedExchange(&ANON_VAR(state), initialized); \
            ANON_VAR(cont) = false;                             \
            break;                                              \
        case initializing:                                      \
            continue;                                           \
        case initialized:                                       \
            ANON_VAR(cont) = false;                             \
            break;                                              \
        }                                                       \
    } do { } while (0)
```

You can use this like

```
void concurrently_accessed() {
    STATIC_DEFINE_ONCE(int, local_var, thread_unsafe_initializer());
    // ...
}
```

This approach takes advantage of zero-initialization of static block-scoped variables, which is required by the C language standard. The above macros will let you safely use "magic" statics until actual compiler & run-time support arrive in [MSVC 2014](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2014/06/03/visual-studio-14-ctp.aspx).

Answer (score 4):

You could put the static data in a function and utilize boost::once:

```
int& get_static() {
    static boost::once_flag once_flag = BOOST_ONCE_INIT;
    static int* data;

    struct Initialize
    {
        static void apply() {
            data = new int(1);
        }
    };
    boost::call_once(once_flag, &Initialize::apply);
    return *data;
}
```

The data will be static initialized at first function call, after that the call once is done.

In http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_32_0/doc/html/call_once.html:

> The call_once function and once_flag type
>   (statically initialized to BOOST_ONCE_INIT) can be used to run a
>   routine exactly once. This can be used to initialize data in a
>   thread-safe manner.

Comment: I am not familiar with boost::call_one. I assume this will make sure the initialization is not called twice, but does it also make sure "data" are already initialized when accessed?

Comment: The data will be static initialized at first function call, after that the call once is done.

Comment: [std::call_once docs](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/call_once) say "No invocation in the group returns before the abovementioned execution of the selected function is completed successfully" which is a guarantee I am looking for, but I do not see it in [boost docs](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_38_0/doc/html/thread/synchronization.html#thread.synchronization.once). Even if it works, I would prefer a solution without boost. I think mimicking what boost::call_once with a mutex should be possible?

Comment: @Suma: if I were you, I'd go with boost. It's guaranteed to be correct and probably the fastest implementation available on your compiler - whatever this is. And it's portable. And you can switch it directly to std::call_once once your compiler supports it. But yes, it can be done with a mutex.